# Symfony Dependency Injection not triggering load function

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

I'm trying out building my own CMS with the Symfony stack and I'm already in some issues with the Dependency Injection.

**What am I trying to do** 
Load the 'Extension' of each module installed on the CMS, so services and doctrine settings can be merged.

**What I am doing**
Running Symfony Flex ( Symfony 4 ) I have in src/Kernel.php: ( in the configureContainer function)

```
foreach ($this->getInstalledModules() as $module) {
    $class = 'App\\Modules\\' . $module . '\\DependencyInjection\\' . $module . 'Extension';
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        $container->registerExtension(new $class());
    }
}
```

I have my modules stored in `src/Modules/[module_name]`, the dependency loader for each module is in `src/Modules/[module_name]/DependencyInjection/[module_name]Extension.php` with namespace `App\Modules\Articles\DependencyInjection`
My extension for a module:

```
class ArticlesExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        die("LOADING");
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('doctrine.yml');
    }
}
```

As you can see I added a `die` for testing purposes, the issue is that this does not get executed ( with or without the die ). The prepend function though gets executed and is working registering my doctrine entities accordingly.

You can find my repository by visiting this link: http://lab.cirykpopeye.be/cirykpopeye/Cirykpopeye.be/tree/development

Comment: Have not used the prepend before but I sort of had the impression that is was more for tweaking configurations of other bundles.  Are you module classes bundle classes?   Seems like you would be registering them in initializeBundles instead of configureContainer?  Is it possible for you to post the complete Kernel code or maybe link to a gtihub repo?

Comment: I edited my post with a gitlab url for the project, it's in the development branch though. Kernel.php sits in src/Kernel.php. My modules will be located at src/Modules/[module_name]