# How to load, process and use custom parameters from Yaml configuration files in DI Extension class?

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony4

I'm trying to import a yaml configuration file in my App following the documentation provided here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html but I always have the error message:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app"

My file is located here : **config/packages/app.yaml** and has the following structure :

```
app:  
    list:  
        model1:  
            prop1: value1
            prop2: value2  
        model2:
            ...
```

As this is a simple App, all the files are in `src/`. So I have **src/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    }
}
```

And **src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

        // Node definition
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('list')
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                    ->prototype('array')
                        ->children()
                            ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                            ->prototype('scalar')
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

I'm not able to access my parameters :(
Any idea?

Comment: In S4 there is no longer an AppBundle so this approach won't work.  If you really need it for some reason then create an AppBundle like S3 has.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to load a custom configuration file to process it's parameters using an Extension class (*like in Symfony bundle extension but without to create a bundle*), to eventually "create" and add one or more of it to the "container" (*before it will be compiled*) you can register your Extension class manually in the `configureContainer` method contained in the `Kernel.php` file:

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    // to avoid the same error you need to put this line at the top
    // if your file is stored under "$this->getProjectDir().'/config'" directory
    $container->registerExtension(new YourAppExtensionClass());

    // ----- rest of the code
}
```

Then you can use your params as usual [registering a Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have not seen this before but it does indeed work.  Bit of documentation on registering extensions outside of bundles: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the link (_initially I wrote the answer very fastly_). Personally I discovered the method looking at the source code of the extended classes (_like I usually do to learn how Symfony works internally_) :-). PS: feel free to improve (_also the grammar_) my answer (_my english it's not so good_).

Comment: Might want to take a look at this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915952/symfony-dependency-injection-not-triggering-load-function?noredirect=1#comment82836242_47915952